# 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, bad-gateway

I am using this link: http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/08/10/drupal-container-on-ibm-bluemix/ to install a Drupal application. But when I try to start the application this message displays: `502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request`.

What do I have to change to prevent the 502 error?